# Problemas con las cookies con PHP y Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, cookies

Estoy creando una app donde tengo que iniciar sesión. Lo que pasa es que al iniciar sesión, ingreso con las credenciales adecuadas y me lleva a la página principal, pero luego me lleva al inicio de nuevo y eso debería pasar cuando no está la **cookie** `remember`. Tengo varias partes de mi código, por una parte mi HTML que contiene el **formulario**, mi Javascript que **verifica el formulario** y crea la cookie `remember` y otro código Javascript que verifica que esté válida mi cookie. Procedo a adjuntar mi código:

Esto que adjunto sería para iniciar sesión, más la comprobación del formulario

```js
const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
const passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
const rememberCheckbox = document.getElementById('remember');
const btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Evitar que el formulario se envíe

  const email = emailInput.value;
  const password = passwordInput.value;

  // Validar el campo de correo electrónico
  if (!email) {
    alert('Por favor ingrese su correo electrónico.');
    return;
  }

  // Validar el campo de contraseña
  if (!password) {
    alert('Por favor ingrese su contraseña.');
    return;
  }

  // Validar el campo de recuerdame
  if (rememberCheckbox.checked) {
    // Establecer una fecha de expiración de la cookie en 10 días
    const now = new Date();
    const time = now.getTime();
    const expireTime = time + 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 10 días
    now.setTime(expireTime);
    document.cookie = `remember=true; expires=${now.toUTCString()}; path=/;`;

    return;
  }

  document.querySelector('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="login.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Tu
                                    email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
      placeholder="name@company.com" required="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
      required="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
    <div class="flex items-start">
      <div class="flex items-center h-5">
        <input id="remember" aria-describedby="remember" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-primary-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800"
          required="">
      </div>
      <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
        <label for="remember" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">Recuerdame</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="text-sm font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500">Olvidaste
                                    la contraseña</a>
  </div>
  <a type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="cursor-pointer w-full text-black hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Iniciar
                                Sesión</a>

</form>
```

Luego, la información esa se envía al archivo php, que crea la cookie sesion:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "**";
$username = "**";
$db_password = "**";
$dbname = "**";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);

// Comprobar la conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    error_log("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error); // Agregar error_log
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Recibir datos del formulario
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$_SESSION["email"] = $email;
// Obtener la contraseña correspondiente al email proporcionado
$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $user_password = $row["password"];
} else {
    error_log("Usuario no encontrado"); // Agregar error_log
    die("Usuario no encontrado");
}

// Verificar la contraseña proporcionada
if ($password == $user_password) {
    // La contraseña es correcta, permite el acceso del usuario
    
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "", false, true);
    header('Location: tests.html');
    exit();
} else {
    error_log("Acceso denegado"); // Agregar error_log
    echo "Acceso denegado";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Si el usuario era el correcto, se **podría** tener acceso a la pagina **tests.html**, pero en realidad lo que sucede es que llego a tests y me devuelve a mi inicio de sesión, esto se debe al siguiente Javascript que va en la parte tests.html. Lo que hace es **validar** la cookie remember:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    let cookie = cookies.length ? cookies.find((curr) => curr.trim().startsWith("remember=")) : undefined;
    let cookievalue = cookie ? cookie.split("=")[1] : undefined;


    if (cookievalue === "true") {
        alert("Log in autorizado"); // te mantiene en la pagina actual
    } else {
        
        window.location.replace("https://prueba"); 
    }
});
```

El tema es que algo no está funcionando como debería y no sé cuál es el error.
Muchas gracias, desde ya.

Comment: Trata de cambiar esta linea en php **setcookie("remember", true, time() + 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "/", "", false, true);** este cambio, la cookie remember creada en PHP tendrá el mismo nombre que la cookie que el código JavaScript busca en tests.html. Con suerte, esto resolverá el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eso estaré intentando. Si te interesa, lo puedes dejar como respuesta. Saludos!